# Emacs org mode: background color of latex fragments (with `org-highlight-latex-and-related`) : which variable to change?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

Ok, so my org-mode latex fragments have a slightly off background color, but only when I:

```lisp
(setq org-highlight-latex-and-related '(native))
```

As seen here
[image]

It looks similar to the background highlighting functionality as involved in `~~` (code).

Does anyone know what to do?

BONUS:

- I'm using doom emacs and the gruvbox theme.

TRIED:

- I don't think this is related to the fragments themselves a la `org-format-latex-options` (as seen in many other posts)
- This is NOT helped by setting `font-latex-math-face :background`

HINTS:

- I feel like it IS related to the face `org-latex-and-related`, but I can work out how the chance the background, when I 'customise' the face i get the following:

```lisp
(defface org-latex-and-related
  (let ((font (cond ((assq :inherit custom-face-attributes)
             '(:inherit underline))
            (t '(:underline t)))))
    `((((class grayscale) (background light))
       (:foreground "DimGray" ,@font))
      (((class grayscale) (background dark))
       (:foreground "LightGray" ,@font))
      (((class color) (background light))
       (:foreground "SaddleBrown"))
      (((class color) (background dark))
       (:foreground "burlywood"))
      (t (,@font))))
  "Face used to highlight LaTeX data, entities and sub/superscript."
  :group 'org-faces
  :version "24.4"
  :package-version '(Org . "8.0"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

As usual, tecosaur [got there first](https://tecosaur.github.io/emacs-config/config.html#prettier-highlighting) and gives a good breakdown of the internals.

The code that does the magic is

```lisp
(require 'org-src)
(add-to-list 'org-src-block-faces '("latex" (:inherit default :extend t)))
```